# Unity. Как заставить Raycast игнорировать родительский объект?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть префаб некого объекта. На нём висит коллайдер и rigidbody. На сцене таких объектов может быть до 1000 и каждый из них должен "видеть" другие объекты, но проблема в том, что Рейкаст преградждается родительским коллайдером. Выставление слоя Ignore Raycast разумеется не решает проблему.

Comment: почему луч не выпускать от родителя тогда?

Comment: Луч как раз от родителя и выпускается. Мне нужно получать дистанцию до коллайдера и сейчас рейкаст возвращает, потому что сразу же врезается в родительский коллайдер.

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько путей:

1. Делать RaycastAll и пропускать родительский коллайдер
2. Выпускать луч не из координат родителя, а чуть подальше
3. Если слои разные у объектов, можешь использовать LayerMask

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема и решил ее так:

> отключить Queries Start In Colliders в настройках проекта (убрать
> галочку)

Вариант может быть не совсем подходящим конкретно для Вашего проекта, но это нужно уже смотреть сам проект. Главное - что конкретную эту проблему оно решить поможет.